# react-native How to get data using AsyncStorage in this.state {}<closed>

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I want to use this.state and setState instead of Redux.
How can i use AsyncStorage.getItems('user') in this.state?

below is my code, however the code is not working.
Do you have any idea?
thanks.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  var value = await ASyncStorage.getItem('user');
  var parsed = JSON.parse(value);

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: parsed.name
    };
  }
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you made a spell mistake ASyncStorage btw use like this and await is only use like

```
try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
  if (value !== null){
    // We have data!!
    console.log(value);
  }
} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
}
```

here is a code modification

```
componentWillMount(){
 var value =  AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
    value.then((e)=>{
      this.setState({
       name: e.name
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jigar.I realized that react-native need redux.